# Why does my DSLR have a 1 minute recording limit?

Tags: video, dslr, recording, nikon

I have a Nikon D7500, which I've been using to record some video.  I know that most DSLRs have a 30 minute recording limit, and mine started off that way as well.  The more I filmed, the more my recording limit time decreased.  I assumed it was because there was too much video storage on the memory card, although the memory card is 16 GB, and I'd only used a couple.  I transferred the videos and images from the memory card to my computer and went to film another video.  The 30 minute recording limit had reset.  After filming one short video, however, the limit decreased to 1 minute and 17 seconds.  I tried transferring the video to my computer, but my camera recording time refuses to change from 1 minute and 17 seconds.  I tried looking for a solution online, and read that the camera might be overheated, so I let it cool and also charged the battery, in case that could have affected it.  I tried googling some more answers, but just found tips for going past the 30 minute limit.  I am fine with a 30 minute limit, and my camera should be too.  Why is the limit staying at 1 minute and 17 seconds?  Ho